# Bash script variable visible from "outside"

Tags: bash, variables, scope

Let's say I create a script where I read a password and save it in a variable, then the script never use this value and only holds it in memory.

Is there a way someone ( root?) can see the variable's value from "outside"?

For instance, someone with sudo access can list the variable's hold by each bash process?

Or read it in a file somewhere?

Or is the above scenario safe?

Comment: Sure, it's called a "debugger".

Comment: @KamilCuk You mean I can use a debugger for a script which is running and also belongs to someone else? Like, "start a debug session on PID X to see what's on it"?

Comment: You can attach debugger to any program running. If your're root, you do anything...

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks!! If you post an answer I'll upvote and check it.